# Keep the corresponding value of another column after using groupby in a column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

After using groupby and agg to find the max and the min, I would like to keep the value of another column corresponding to said Max and Min.

What I have:

| Order | Missing | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Order 1 | Missing 1 | 2002 |
| Order 1 | Missing 2 | 2003 |
| Order 2 | Missing 3 | 2004 |
| Order 2 | Missing 4 | 2005 |
| Order 2 | Missing 5 | 2006 |
| Order 3 | Missing 6 | 2007 |

What I do

```
calculation = df.groupby(by=('Order')).agg(Max=('Date','max'),Min=('Date','min')).reset_index()
calculation['difference'] = calculation['Max']-calculation['Min']
```

What I get

| Order | Min | Max | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Order 1 | 2002 | 2003 | 1 year |
| Order 2 | 2004 | 2006 | 2 years |
| Order 3 | 2007 | 2007 | 0s |

What I want,

| Order | Min | Max | difference | Missing Min | Missing Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Order 1 | 2002 | 2003 | 1 year | Missing 1 | Missing 2 |
| Order 2 | 2004 | 2006 | 2 years | Missing 3 | Missing 5 |
| Order 3 | 2007 | 2007 | 0s | Missing 6 | Missing 6 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `merge`. Two more lines in your code would get you what you want.

```
calculation["Missing Min"] = calculation.merge(
    df, left_on=["Order", "Min"], right_on=["Order", "Date"]
)["Missing"]
calculation["Missing Max"] = calculation.merge(
    df, left_on=["Order", "Max"], right_on=["Order", "Date"]
)["Missing"]
```

print(calculation):

```
             Order   Max   Min  difference Missing Min Missing Max
0          Order 1   2003  2002           1  Missing 1   Missing 2 
1          Order 2   2006  2004           2  Missing 3   Missing 5 
2          Order 3   2007  2007           0  Missing 6   Missing 6
```

Comment: KeyError: 'Missing'. 
Can it be because calculation does not have a Missing column?

Comment: If you have "Missing" column in your "df" - the original one, you shouldn't see this error.

Comment: Worked perfectly after a reset index of the original dataframe. It is also very fast

Answer (score 2):

I would use separate `groupby` and a `merge`:

```
g = df.groupby(by='Order')

(pd.merge(df.loc[g['Date'].idxmin()]
            .rename({'Date': 'Min', 'Missing': 'Missing Min'}, axis=1),
          df.loc[g['Date'].idxmax()]
            .rename({'Date': 'Max', 'Missing': 'Missing Max'}, axis=1),
          on='Order')
   .assign(difference=lambda d: d['Max']-d['Min'])
)
```

Output:

```
     Order Missing Min   Min Missing Max   Max  difference
0  Order 1   Missing 1  2002   Missing 2  2003           1
1  Order 2   Missing 3  2004   Missing 5  2006           2
2  Order 3   Missing 6  2007   Missing 6  2007           0
```

Comment: Very clean and works, but I need to make some research on idx and lambda to understand why

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to add additional group by calculations/columns, similiar to how you created "Max" and "Min" columns from "Date". (I apologize, I am not able to debug code right now).:

```
calculation = df.groupby(by=('Order')).agg(Max=('Date','max'),Min=('Date','min'), Missing_Min=('Missing','min'), Missing_Max=('Missing','max')).reset_index()
calculation['difference'] = calculation['Max']-calculation['Min']
```